# How to check if element exists in JSON array?

Tags: json, find, d

```
Json test = Json.emptyArray;
test ~= "aaa";
test ~= "bbb";
test ~= "ccc";
writeln(test);
```

output: `["aaa","bbb","ccc"]`

But How I can check if this array have element? I can't figure how to use `canFind` with JSON array. I am using [vibed json module](http://vibed.org/api/vibe.data.json/).

```
if(test.get!string[].canFind("aaa"))
{
    writeln("founded");
}
```

Does not work: `Got JSON of type array, expected string.`

If to do like this:

```
if(test.get!(string[]).canFind("aaa"))
{
    writeln("founded");
}
```

`Error: static assert  "Unsupported JSON type 'string[]'. Only bool, long, std.bigint.BigInt, double, string, Json[] and Json[string] are allowed."`

With `to!string` and `toString` methods all work:

```
Json test = Json.emptyArray;
test ~= "aaa";
test ~= "bbb";
test ~= "ccc";
writeln(to!string(test));

if(test.toString.canFind("aaa"))
{
    writeln("founded");
}
```

But if I do it's inside foreach:

```
foreach(Json v;visitorsInfo["result"])
{
if((v["passedtests"].toString).canFind("aaa"))
 {
    writeln("founded");
 }
}
```

I am getting: `Error: v must be an array or pointer type, not Json`. What's wrong?

Comment: Can you try putting braces around your string []? Like .get! (string []).canFind

Comment: I updated code. Is it's possible that I can get error while passing array to `writeln`? Is it's support printing arrays?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. Was on the phone, so get!(string[]) won't work. It must be converted to one of these types: http://vibed.org/api/vibe.data.json/Json.get

Comment: @ColinGrogan
But what's wrong with my foreach loop? What does this error mean?

Comment: Are you getting it at compile time or runtime?

Comment: Scratch that - I suspect it's canFind.

Use my canFind implementation below. it'll work for you. 

The compiler will give you the line nubmer that's going wrong too - might be good to post that up here too so we know what we're looking at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON array objects are arrays of other JSON elements. They are not arrays of strings, which is why `elem.get!(string[])` fails at compile time.

Slice the JSON element to get an array of sub-elements, then use `canFind`'s predicate argument to get a string from each of the sub-elements.

```
writeln(test[].canFind!((a,b) => a.get!string == b)("foo"));
```

Comment: I much prefer this solution. Didn't even realise canFind could take a predicate!

Answer (score 0):

This works - though isn't particularly nice.

```
void main(){

    Json test = Json.emptyArray;

    test ~= "foo";
    test ~= "bar";
    test ~= "baz";

    foreach(ele; test){
        if(ele.get!string == "foo") {
            writeln("Found 'foo'");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Could put it in a helper function like so:

```
bool canFind(T)(Json j, T t){
  assert(j.type == Json.Type.array, "Expecting json array, not: " ~ j.type.to!string);

  foreach(ele; j){
    // Could put some extra checks here, to ensure ele is same type as T.
    // If it is the same type, do the compare. If not either continue to next ele or die
    // For the purpose of this example, I didn't bother :)

    if(ele.get!T == t){
       return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

// To use it
if(test.canFind("foo")){
  writefln("Found it");
}
```